# Docker automated build not being triggered

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Prob something very obvious, just not to me. Automated builds in Docker are not triggered when I push to master branch on github. repo is at https://github.com/lukewendling/embed-map - Dockerfile at root of project. My build settings shown here: http://snag.gy/iGYs6.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within GitHub, does a Docker integration appears in your repositories Settings > Webhooks & services page? is it active?

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/ `Create an automated build` section, 6th bullet point.

Comment: good idea. i checked on github and it seems to be configured and active. i re-added anyway. builds were working from docker hub previously, when i manually triggered it, so i assume that means the service was active. so not sure what was going on but this as as good an idea as any.